# Dynamic Importing with Pyinstaller Executable

Tags: python, pyinstaller, dynamic-import

I’m trying to write a script that dynamically imports and uses any modules a user places in a folder. The dynamic importing works fine when I’m running it via python, but when I try to compile it into a Pyinstaller executable, it breaks down and throws me a ModuleNotFoundError, saying it can't find a module with the same name as the folder the modules are placed in. The executable sits alongside this folder, which contains all the modules to be dynamically imported, so my import statements look like `__import__("FOLDERNAME.MODULENAME")`. The script must be able to run the modules dropped in this folder without being recompiled. What's strange is that the ModuleNotFoundError says `No module named 'FOLDERNAME'`, despite that just being the name of the folder containing the modules, I'd expect it to complain about `No module named 'FOLDERNAME.MODULENAME'` instead.

In my googling, I found this question ([pyinstaller: adding dynamically loaded modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399311/pyinstaller-adding-dynamically-loaded-modules)), which is pretty similar, but the answer they provided from the docs doesn’t really help. How do I give additional files on the command line if I don’t know what files are going to be in the folder in the first place? That kind of beats the purpose of dynamic importing. I've attempted to use the hidden-import command line flag, but the compiler output said `Hidden import '[X]' not found`. Maybe I'm just using it wrong? And I have no idea how to modify the spec file or write a hook file to do what I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I was working on a similar functionality to implement a Plugin Architecture and ran into the same issue. Quoting @[Gao Yuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1594371/gao-yuan) from a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399311/pyinstaller-adding-dynamically-loaded-modules) :-

> Pyinstaller (currently v 3.4) can't detect imports like importlib.import_module(). The issue and solutions are detailed in Pyinstaller's documentation, which I pasted below as an entry point.

But of-course there is always a way. Instead you can use `importlib.util.spec_from_file_location` to load and then compile the module

### Minimum wokring example

##### iterface.py

```
# from dependency import VARIABLE
# from PySide6.QtCore import Qt

def hello_world():
    print(f"this is a plugin calling QT {Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignAbsolute}")
    print(f"this is a plugin calling DEPENDENCY {VARIABLE}")
```

##### cli.py

```
import sys
import types
from pprint import pprint
import importlib.util
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    module_name = "dependency"
    module_file = "plugins/abcplugin/dependency.py"
    if spec:=importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_file):
        dependency = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        sys.modules[module_name] = dependency
        spec.loader.exec_module(dependency)

    module_name = "interface"
    module_file = "plugins/abcplugin/interface.py"
    if spec:=importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, module_file):
        interface = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
        sys.modules[module_name] = interface
        spec.loader.exec_module(interface)

    sys.modules[module_name].hello_world()
```

##### project structure

```
cli.exe
plugins
    abcplugin
        __init__.py
        interface.py
        dependency.py

    complus
        __init__.py
        ...
```

#### Thumb Rules

- `Plugin` must always be relative to .exe
- As you can notice I commented out `# from dependency import VARIABLE` in line one of `interface.py`. If you scripts depend on scripts in the same plugin, then you must load `dependency.py` before loading `interface.py`.  You can then un-comment the line.
- In `pyinstaller.spec` file you need to add `hiddenimports` in this case `PySide6` and then un-comment `# from PySide6.QtCore import Qt`
- Always use absolute imports when designing a plugin in reference to your project root folder. You can then set the module name to `plugins.abcplugin.interface` and `plugins.abcplugin.dependency` and also update `from dependency import VARIABLE` to `from plugins.abcplugin.dependency import VARIABLE`

Hope people find this usefull, cheers!!